# TextBoxFor model incrementing dynamically in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, loops, razor

I am building a web application for working out. When a work out day loads, it displays a FORM that has a series of text boxes for each exercise to record the amount of repetitions and the weight done for each set. Each exercise requires a different amount of sets.

I created a class that holds two object types, a list of exercises from an ExerciseReference entity class/database table, and an entity class for recording the data that the user enters into the form and submits.

My model looks like this:

```
public class ExerciseListModel
{
    public List<ExerciseRef> exercises { get; set; }
    public ExerciseREC recordedExercises { get; set; }
}
```

When building the Reps and Weights text boxes for each exercise, my Razor HTML looks similar to this:

```
 @foreach(ExerciseRef item in Model.exercises)
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
            <h3>@item.Name.ToString()</h3>
            </div>
            <p>@item.Description.ToString()</p>

                for (int i = 0; i < item.NumberOfSets; i++)
                {                        
                   <text>Set #: </text> @(i + 1)<br />
                   <text>REPS: </text> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.recordedExercises.Set1Reps)<br />
                   <text>WEIGHT: </text> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.recordedExercises.Set1Weight) <br /><br />

                }

        }
```

So essentially, this is a for loop within a foreach loop. The foreach loop builds the HTML list of all of the exercises, while the for loop builds the text boxes for reps and weights.

I need the number in Set1Reps in the following line:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.recordedExercises.Set1Reps)
```

To be dynamic and increment with the loop. I need it to have Set1Reps for Set 1, and change to Set2Reps for Set 2, and so on and so forth.

Any idea how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your data model to contain sets and reps as collections on the recordedExcercises property.  Then, you can iterate over them like you are iterating over the entire collection of exercises.